# How to return a big XML response in C# Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a web api which need to create large XML responses according to various requests. I tried googling but all the answers are about XMLSerializer.
And I tried making XDocument object and returning it using toString() method.
But it's not working properly too. It gives me output like this

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"><root> <someNode>someValue</someNode> </root></string>
```

Isn't there an easy way to generate XML dynamically and return it.

Comment: You can use XDocument to create dynamic XML, it all depends how you are using it.

Comment: can you give me any example please?

Comment: Please write the method where you are getting the dynamic data. Explain what you want in node and what you want as attribute if you can

Comment: Request is bunch of numbers. Response contains description elements for each number. That is the basic. But it is more complex than that which i can't explain here.

Comment: Why can't you use XMLSerializer?

Comment: Basically i need to use XML attributes. [XMLAttribute] didn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of generating XML dynamically, Why don't to use collection of class. Make a generic class and assign the data in collection. Send the collection using media header as xml.

```
request.Headers.Accept.Clear();
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
```